# How do I add values to a logstash configuration array?

Tags: configuration, logstash

I'd like to add the field 'calculated_level' to the 'ignore_metadata' configuration option on the GELF output. I see that this configuration option has the following default values set:

> ["@timestamp", "@version", "severity", "host", "source_host",
>   "source_path", "short_message"]

I'd like to add 'calculated_level' to these default values, not override them. How do I add to default values?

I assume that if I simply do the below, that will override the default values set for the 'ignore_metadata' configuration option.

```
  gelf {
    host => 'localhost'
    full_message => ''
    level => ['%{calculated_level}','INFO']
    ignore_metadata => ['calculated_level']
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how it's possible to append values to the default.

Comment: Alright, so the way to go is to list the defaults again and just add my own extra fields then.

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin you are using doesn't have `add_field` function, you can use a mutate plugin in your filter where you can use `remove_field` to remove `ignore_metadata`  field at first and then use `add_field` to add `ignore_metadata` with the new value.